# User shown on recent questions list doesn't appear to have edited anything.

Tags: support

In looking at https://gis.stackexchange.com/, I see dslamb next to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/using-local-mbtiles-in-openlayers):

[image]

But when I open the question page, I don't see dslamb mentioned anywhere.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a vestige: dslamb deleted his reply.